# Prove that $|x|\le a$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, theorem-provers

How can I prove this?

$|x|\le a$, $\space \space$ $\:-a\le x\le a\:, $ $\space \space$ $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks!

Comment: take any $a$, for example $a=5$. Now try to see for what values of $x$, your inequality holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|x|\le a$

If $$x\le 0,  ~then~ -x \le a \implies x \ge -a \implies  x\in [-a, 0]$$

If $$x\ge 0,  ~then~ x \le a \implies x \in [0, a] $$

The final result is union of these two intervals: $x\in [-a,a]$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$|x|=x, x\ge0$$
$$|x|=-x, x\le 0$$
Now suppose $x \in [0,a]$, $x \le a \implies |x| \le a$
and so if $x \in [-a,0]$, $x \ge -a \implies -x \le a \implies |x| \le a$.